# Delete NA Columns in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I have a dataframe with 75 columns out of which 12 columns are having all NA's and some with 70% NA's. I want to delete columns having >=70% NA's.

Can anyone help me in this? I tried

```
df[,! apply( df , 2 , function(x) all(is.na(x)) )
```

but I am getting exception as:

> Error: Unable to retreive a spark_connection from object of class NULL

I also tried:

```
df[colSums(!is.na(df)) != nrow(df)]
```

and

```
df[, colSums(is.na(df)) < nrow(df)]
```

But I am getting exception as

> Error in colSums(!is.na(df)) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bit tricky in `sparklyr`, but, we can get the index of the columns that needs to be removed from the local copy of dataset and use `select` to remove those columns

```
j1 <- which(!colSums(!is.na(df)))
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
df_tbl <- copy_to(sc, df)
library(dplyr)
df_tbl %>% 
         select(-j1)
# Source:   query [20 x 2]
#Database: spark connection master=local[4] app=sparklyr #local=TRUE

#    col2        col3
#   <int>       <dbl>
#1      1 -1.31690812
#2      1  0.59826911
#3      4 -0.76221437
#4      3 -1.42909030
#5      3  0.33224445
#6      5 -0.46906069
#7      1 -0.33498679
#8      4  1.53625216
#9      4  0.60999453
#10     1  0.51633570
#11     3 -0.07430856
#12     2 -0.60515695
#13     4 -1.70964518
#14     4 -0.26869311
#15     1 -0.64859151
#16     5 -0.09411013
#17     1 -0.08554095
#18    NA  0.11953107
#19     3 -0.11629639
#20    NA -0.94382724
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(col1 = NA_real_, col2 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 20, 
               replace = TRUE), col3 = rnorm(20))
```

Comment: Issue with this solution is, I don't know which columns are NA's. It cannot be a static list. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Mansoor  You don't have to know.  It is programmatically found from the first line of code `j1 <- which(!colSums(!is.na(df)))`

Comment: Akrun, as I have mentioned, columns need not be all NA's. 70% NA's

Comment: @Mansoor  My code was based on the code you showed in your post.  If that is not the case, then we can easily sorted this out

Comment: @Mansoor if it is 70%, then change 'j1' to `ji <- which(colSums(is.na(df))/nrow(df) >= 0.7)`

Comment: the main aim of using spark is to handle big datasets, working with a local copy of the datas and more of that, using copy_to(sc,df) which doesn't support big datasets, your solution seems not usefull to me.

Comment: @user1767316  Okay, then try posting a new question.  Anyway, this post is bit old,